# Use HTML parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am a starting with flask/html/javascript and I have this issue:

**I render a template from python:**

```
return render_template("loading.html", process='abc')
```

**This es the content of loading.html file**

```
<body>
<div class="titulo">
    <p>here I see the value of parameter sent {{process}}</p>
</div>
    <div class="loader">
</div>

<script>
function navigate() {
    window.location.href = 'process_b';
}
fetch('process_a').then(navigate);
</script>
</body>
```

*This small code works fine it executes process_a then process_b but the question is: **How can I use the parameter "process" inside the javascript?**
I have tried using:*

**document.getElementById("process").value**

but it does not work

Can someone please help me?

Best regards

document.getElementById("process").value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject values for JavaScript like this:

```
<script>
  let process = "{{ process }}";
</script>
```

That is for a string. If it is a number, you don't need the quotes.

Comment: Thanks Jarno. That answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the HTML that's returned from the API.

```js
function navigate(html) {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
  let process = doc.querySelector(".titulo p").innerText;
  console.log(process);
}

fetch('process_a')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(navigate);
```

The value is in the text of a `<p>` tag, not the value of an input.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by making a small change in the template code as below

```
<div class="titulo">
    <p>here I see the value of parameter sent <span id="process">{{process}}</span></p>
</div>
```

I have added `span` tag with `id` attribute with `value = process` which can be now accessed in javascript by using the below code.

```
document.getElementById("process").value
```

Hope it solves your issue.